# Select dropdown is not working in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have got the error  `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException Element should have been "select" but was "span"`. Can you please help?

I have tried this code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='month']//span[@class='next-select-inner']"));
        Select select = new Select(element);
        select.selectByVisibleText("November");
```

Comment: What you have tried?Where the issue occurs? you would have used the `select` class where the select tag will not be there in the respective selector. It will help us to make it resolved if you post the HTML Dom code and code you have tried

Comment: I have tried this WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='month']//span[@class='next-select-inner']"));
  Select select = new Select(element);
  select.selectByVisibleText("November");

Answer (score 2):

`new Select(element)` expects an [`<SELECT>` HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element e.g. `By.xpath("//select")` not a [`<SPAN>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp). Probaly the implementation of your dropdown is not a HTML Select Tag, but it is a JavaScript custom dropdown. You cannot use the Select helpers.

I think you just need to:

- Find the dropdown SPAN
- Click on the dropdown SPAN
- Wait for an element with text November
- Click on the found element.

Answer (score 0):

Many companies provide software testing solutions to the problems faced by clients. In this problem, whenever we are using 'Select' method of selenium, the Webelement Tag must be "Select". The web element mentioned in the question of 'Span' Tag.

In order to select any element from the dropdown having Tag other than Select, we can do by using click actions.